# Composite keys issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, fluent, ef-database-first

I need some help here. I have two solution's that give need to give same result. One of them work's fine, but another dosen't work.

```
public class Calculation
 {
  public int ClacID { get; set; }
  public string CalcNumber { get; set; }
  public string BillNumber { get; set; }
  public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

  public Company Company { get; set; }
  public int SupplierID { get; set; }
  public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int? RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public CompanyRegister CompanyRegister { get; set; }
    public string OwnerFirstname { get; set; }
    public string OwnerLastname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public string Telefax { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyType { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public Users User { get; set; }

    //References
    public List<Calculation> CalculationList { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Place = new Place();
        CompanyRegister = new CompanyRegister();
        CalculationList = new List<Calculation>();
    }

}
```

Configuration:

```
public class CalculationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Calculation>
    {
        public CalculationConfiguration()
        {
            // Set Table
            ToTable("Calculation");

            // Primary
            HasKey(p => p.ClacID);

            //Foreign Keys
            HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company)
                .WithMany(c => c.CalculationList)
                .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.CompanyID, d.SupplierID });

            //HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.CalculationList).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyID);
            //HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.CalculationList).HasForeignKey(c => c.SupplierID);

            //Map
            Property(p => p.ClacID).HasColumnName("CalcID");
            Property(p => p.CompanyID).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
            Property(p => p.CalcNumber).HasColumnName("CalcNumber").HasMaxLength(10);
            Property(p => p.SupplierID).HasColumnName("SupplierID");
            Property(p => p.BillNumber).HasColumnName("BillNumber").HasMaxLength(100);
            Property(p => p.BillDate).HasColumnName("BillDate");
            Property(p => p.CreateDate).HasColumnName("CreateDate");
            Property(p => p.ModifiedDate).HasColumnName("ModifiedDate");
            Property(p => p.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted");
        }
    }
```

Don't work:

```
        //Foreign Keys
        HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.CalculationList)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.CompanyID, d.SupplierID });
```

Working:

```
HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.CalculationList).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyID);
HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.CalculationList).HasForeignKey(c => c.SupplierID);
```

Can somebody in the world tell me. What's wrong ?

Thanks.
Zlaja

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - what errors/bad results are you getting?

Comment: Hi i get this exception when I want add to db.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:



DataAccess.Logging: : EntityType 'Logging' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Comment: Calculation_Company_Target_Calculation_Company_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Logging: EntityType: EntitySet 'Logging' is based on type 'Logging' that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-

```
 //Foreign Keys
        HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.CalculationList)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new Company { d.CompanyID, d.SupplierID });
```

Answer (score 0):

EF (up to 6.1) only accepts to set relationships between PK in the main entity and FK in the dependent entity.

You cannot specify that FK to `Company` becasue it depends on something more than `CompanyId`, with is the `Company`'s PK.

You can neither set a relationship based on an AK. But in your sample code, it's not even an AK (alternate key = set of columns with unique constraint = candidate key).

Why don't you set the relationship only to the PK `CompanyId`? Using something different to a PK or an AK makes no sense.

By the way, if it's really an AK, and you want that functionality, go to [EF user's voice site](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions), and vote for it (it's usualy the most demanded functionality)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. If I understand you correctly. This is only my solution for moment:

HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.CalculationList).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyID);
HasRequired<Company>(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.CalculationList).HasForeignKey(c => c.SupplierID);